# How to convert a excel file data to json in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a requirement that have to download file from dropbox and have to show data from that excel in a table view. so, i am accessing file from dropbox using Document Picker and collecting the url.

Though i am getting file path but i am unable to see what data it has contain. i also have to convert it's data to json format as well.

Here is my url which i am getting from didPickDocumentAt delegate :-

https://www.dropbox.com/referrer_cleansing_redirect?hmac=AxGHdzUuYb8ym34giAMvTspxR7RB3JhozQ849pTt1rQ%3D&url=http%3A%2F%2F%2Fprivate%2Fvar%2Fmobile%2FContainers%2FShared%2FAppGroup%2F73AF09BC-F5D7-437A-906A-9FEC6F8B81A2%2FFile%2520Provider%2520Storage%2F1903289376%2Flocal-storage%2FL3dlbGwgYXNzaXN0IG9pbGZpZWxkXzMueGxzYg%3D%3D%2Fwell%2520assist%2520oilfield_3.xlsb

So, is there any other way to do it or am i following the right way. if yes then what i am missing or if no then let me know any other approach to do so.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not really important how you get the `.xlsx` file, what's important is how you process it.  Which is non-trivial.  Very very non-trivial.

Comment: @trojanfoe can you tell me how do i access data from this url.

Comment: Do you mean how you open up the `.xlsx` file in order to access the spreadsheet data inside?

Comment: I mean how do i get whatever data inside that file to convert to a specific format.

Comment: It's a zip file of `.xml` files (ignoring any embedded images) which are not hugely complicated to parse.  I cannot provide a one-click solution to you, however, as it's too complicated a subject.  Better would be to access the data via a different format (for example `.csv`) if you can convince whoever is supplying it to change.

Comment: so can you just tell me how can i convert .xlsx file to .csv format .

Comment: No my point was that `.xlsx` is difficult to extract the data from, so perhaps try and get the data as `.csv` instead.